# Azure datastorage table dump to csv

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have an Azure Storage table that has huge data.

I want to compare the data present in that table.

For that I need to query each and every data, for querying one data it takes about 10 mins, and table has lacks of data.

I'm planning to get the dump of the data to CSV where I can compare the data.

Can some please help me out and let me know how to get the data from azure storage loaded into CSV file, Java would be my preferred way of but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I only found the C# nuget package to do the job. [CsvTools.Azure](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvTools.azure) could read and write CSV file to and from Azure Blob And Table. You could have a try.

And here is the blog about how to use it:[Converting between Azure Tables and CSV](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2012/08/03/converting-between-azure-tables-and-csv/).

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know but i adopted to java which is my prefered way!